# Arduino interrupt sleep mode/reset problem

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to write a simple program that waits for an X amount of time (hours) then activates my components (LED and release mechanism) when time has elapsed. I have it so that once I press a button interrupt (pin2) it will put the Arduino in power-down sleep mode when I am not using the device.

What I want it to do next is when another button interrupt (pin3) is pushed, it will wake it up but **instead of resuming where it left off in the loop, I want it to reset the program to the start of the loop.** I am having trouble getting it to reset after it has woken. Is the code actually putting the Arduino in sleep mode? I'm not sure because after the if statement I make the variable false.

Here is my simple code so far:

```
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
//Pin set up
int ledPin =12;
int wakePin = 3;
int sleepPin =2;
volatile boolean flag;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sleepPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(wakePin, INPUT_PULLUP );
  attachInterrupt(0, sleepy, LOW);
  attachInterrupt(1,EMPTY,LOW);
}    

void EMPTY(){
  detachInterrupt(1);
}

void sleepy(){
  flag = true;
}

void sleepNow() {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
  sleep_enable();
  attachInterrupt(1,EMPTY,LOW);
  sleep_mode();
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite (ledPin, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  if (flag) {
    sleepNow();
  }
  flag = false;
}
```

Comment: Why does `sleepNow()` call `detachInterupt(1)`?

Comment: Here is my new code I got it to work on accident by using a boolean. But Now i need to get it to reset when waken.